# Can I Append Custom Highlights to an Existing Syntax Without Forking It?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I'm looking to add a few custom syntax highlights to an existing one, but I don't want to maintain a copy of the base one I'm using in its entirety. Is there a way to extend an existing syntax (and continue to do so through updating, if possible) and just append a few new rules to it?

I've tried using `extends: Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax` in my own .sublime-syntax file, but I get a console error for "**syntax inheritance does not allow for mixed versions**" and I have no idea what that means. I don't see it mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html#inheritance) either. Help?

Comment: The documentation has a section under embedding named `Limitations` in which it says `A syntax may extend a syntax that itself extends another syntax. There are no enforced limits on extending, other than that all syntaxes must share the same version`; the word `version` is a link to a separate section of the same document that discusses what versions are; not having one is assumed to be version `1`, but `HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax` includes `version: 2`; thus you need to also include that in your Syntax in order to extend it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that! I'll give that a try.

Comment: @OdatNurd can you make that an answer?

Comment: Yea! It worked, so you should get credit for being right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Documentation on Syntax Definitions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html) has a [section on inheritance](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html#inheritance) and how you do it; there a section on Limitations:

> A syntax may extend a syntax that itself extends another syntax. There are no enforced limits on extending, other than that all syntaxes must share the same version.

`version` is a new concept in recent versions of Syntaxes; it's listed under [compatibility](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html#compatibility). The general gist is that there are various things about syntaxes which are either bugs or unexpected/undesirable behaviour, but since there are so many syntaxes already available that would be broken if that behaviour was changed, the concept of `version` was added so that newer syntaxes can avail themselves of fixes.

As a result, as mentioned above all syntaxes must be the same `version`, ostensibly so that their behaviour is consistent. Syntaxes that are newly rewritten/revamped in Sublime Text 4 use the new version, and the `HTML` syntax is one of them.

Hence, you need to include `version: 2` in your syntax to be able to extend the HTML syntax.